# Multiple Jobs in One PHP file with Crunz

Tags: php, cron, cakephp-3.0, cron-task

I'm using https://github.com/lavary/crunz to make my CakePHP 3.0 cronjob calls.

The readme says: "The idea is very simple: instead of a installing cron jobs in a crontab file, we define them in one or several PHP files, by using the Crunz interface."

I want to define all my cronjobs in only one PHP file, but all the examples I could get showed only one job per file.

Does someone knows how to do multiple cronjobs in one file using Crunz?

Comment: I think you do not understand that correctly. First of all no pro-programmer will ever keep multiple cron jobs in same file. What is more: `* * * * * /project/vendor/bin/crunz schedule:run` will collect all your jobs from different files. It only needs single cron job file to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  Crunz\Schedule::run() method registers and returns a new event each time you call it, so you can create many tasks with many calls to run(). A rough example probably looks like:

```
<?php
// tasks/backupTasks.php

use Crunz\Schedule;

$schedule = new Schedule();

// Register your first task
$schedule->run('cp project project-bk')       
         ->daily();

// Register another task
$schedule->run('other-task taskparam1 taskparam1')
         ->hourly();

return $schedule;
```